# mongodb: cannot insertMany to MongoDB Atlas server using google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking to store data into Mongodb from a mobile api-call. I'm using google cloud function to send data from mobile client to MongoDB Atlas. I've tried using the following code, however it seems to ignore `newData` array, nothing is being sent and MongoDB Db remains empty.

below is the current solution:

```js
    let newData = {
           transId: trans['trans_id'] ? trans['trans_id'] : '',
           sender: trans['ledger_to_id'] ? trans['ledger_to_id'] : '',
           receiver: trans['ledger_from_id'] ? trans['ledger_from_id'] : '',
           createdAt: trans['created_at'] ? trans['created_at'] : '',
           amount: trans['cost'] ? trans['cost'] : ''
         };
    db.collection('test').insertMany(newData)
    db.close();
```

I've tried `db.collection('test').bulkWrite(newData)`

The full function:

`index.js`

```js
    exports.costLedger = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
      var allTrans = await get(`v1/customer/orders`);
      MongoClient.connect(CONNECTION_URL, function(err, client) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected successfully to server");
        const db = client.db(DATABASE_NAME);
        for (var transIndex in allTrans) {
          var trans = allTrans[transIndex];
          console.log(trans['trans_id']);
          let newData = {
            transId: trans['trans_id'] ? trans['trans_id'] : '',
            sender: trans['ledger_to_id'] ? trans['ledger_to_id'] : '',
            receiver: trans['ledger_from_id'] ? trans['ledger_from_id'] : '',
            createdAt: trans['created_at'] ? trans['created_at'] : '',
            amount: trans['cost'] ? trans['cost'] : ''
          };
          db.collection('test').insertMany(newData)
          db.close();
        }
      });
      return allTrans;
    })
```

Edit: Function is able to connect to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/):

> `document` An array of documents to insert into the collection.

Just add a pair of square brackets around your object:

```
let newData = [{
    transId: trans['trans_id'] ? trans['trans_id'] : '',
    sender: trans['ledger_to_id'] ? trans['ledger_to_id'] : '',
    receiver: trans['ledger_from_id'] ? trans['ledger_from_id'] : '',
    createdAt: trans['created_at'] ? trans['created_at'] : '',
    amount: trans['cost'] ? trans['cost'] : ''
}];
```

Comment: @JackBashford....I received the error: ```>      at /Users/apple/Project/mongodb-trans-data/functions/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:433:24
>  (node:3921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 406)
>  (node:3921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: topology was destroyed ```

Comment: Thanks Jack, that's managed to fix it. I've fixed the bug issue previously, with a simple rearrangement of the code.